# extract subset of imported json file in vue's data() function

Tags: json, vue.js

I have imported the following json file:

```
[
    {
        "case_id": "1234",
        "thread": [
            {
                "t_id": "1111",
                "text": "test"
            },
            {
                "t_id": "2222",
                "text": "test"
            }           
        ]
    },
    {
        "case_id": "5678",
        "thread": [
            {
                "t_id": "9999",
                "text": "test"
            },
            {
                "t_id": "8888",
                "text": "test"
            },
            {
                "t_id": "777",
                "text": "test"
            }       
        ]
    }
]
```

using the following:

```
import cases from '../cases.json'
```

The whole json dataset is available in **cases** variable and can be used in the template with the support of v-if and v-for.

How can I create a separate dataset ***(thecase)*** that contains only threads for a given case_id? In the template I would only like to use v-for to display all threads for a given case_id.

Below is my **export default** section:

```
export default {
    name: "details",
    props: {
      case_id: {
          required: true,
          type: String
      }
    },
    data () {
      return {
          cases,
          thecase: ### THIS IS THE PART I CANNOT FIGURE OUT ###
      }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `thecase` from data options and use a computed property instead for `thecase`. Inside the computed property, we will need to use array [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to find the case where `case_id` is same as the `case_id` passed in the `prop`:

```
data: {
  cases,
},
computed: {
  thecase: function() {
    return this.cases.find(c => c.case_id === (this.case_id || ''))
  }
}
```

and then you can use `v-for` on `thecase.thread` just like you would do for a data option like:

```
<li v-for="item in thecase.thread" :key="item.t_id">
   {{ item.text }}
</li>
```

You can further modify it and use `v-if` & `v-else` to show a text like `No cases were found with give case id` in case there is no match found.